# Map function explanation

Tags: arrays, dictionary, swift3, map-function

Someone can explain me that piece of code because I can't understand well. I find this code and I can't understand notably this line : Room(dict: $0)

```
var rooms: [Room] = [] // The globale variable

func refresh() {
    let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "\(Config.serverUrl)/rooms")!)
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: OperationQueue.main, completionHandler: { resp, data, err in
        guard err == nil else {
            return
        }
        let rooms = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions()) as! [[String: AnyObject]]
        self.rooms = rooms.map {
            Room(dict: $0) // I can't understand this line
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}
```

My Room struct:

```
struct Room {

var key: String
var title: String
var cat: String!

init(dict: [String: AnyObject]) {
    title = dict["title"] as! String
    key = dict["key"] as! String
    cat = dict["cat"] as! String
}

init(key: String, title: String, cat: String) {
    self.key = key
    self.title = title
    self.cat = cat
}

func toDict() -> [String: AnyObject] {
    return [
        "title": title as AnyObject,
        "key": key as AnyObject,
        "cat": cat as AnyObject
    ]
}
}
```

If someone can help me to understand and explain it, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map function loops over every item in a collection, and applies an operation to each element in the collection.

This piece of code

```
self.rooms = rooms.map {
    Room(dict: $0)
}
```

is a short form of this.

```
// `dict` paramater is `$0` in shorter form
self.rooms = rooms.map { (dict : [String: AnyObject]) -> Room in
    return Room(dict: dict)
}
```

Comment: ok thank you it's more clear but the "dict" parameter is what exactly?

Comment: `dict` is an object from the array of type `[String : AnyObject]`

Comment: ok I see it is the parameter in the init function of the struct Room, thank you I understand better